# How is the data consistent when we have many instances of the same spout running in Apache Storm

Tags: apache-storm

I want to use Apache Storm in one of my project. I have a concern regarding its parallelism technique. By definition we can give hints on how many instances of the components we want to run.
For example if there are 4 executors running the same spout, which itself is supposed to read data from external source and transform it into tuples, **how does Storm ensures that no two or many spout get the same data.**

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good question - anyways it looks like the Storm communitiy is a bit "dead".. same is true for the e-mail lists, where I did not get responses. Hope you`ll find an answer anyways!

Comment: @moosehead42 Thanks...
What I have realised is, there are many integration APIs available which wraps the basic Spout  implementation to handle consistency, if you dont find any for your purpose, you need to write your own. :)